# Writing a function that takes two strings as input and replaces it with asterisks

Tags: python

I am on Codecademy exercise 10/15. The goal is to create a censor function that 
take the string "this hack is wack" and replace it with "this **** is wack"

```
def censor("this hack is wack", "hack"):
     def "h,a,c,k".split():
          for letter in list: 
                       "*" 4
                "".join(list)
    return list
```

1) Im pretty sure that you don't need to define a function inside of a function so would I store the split function as a variable?

2) How would I rewrite the .join function to get the new sentence with the asterisks after it is done looping through each letter in hack

Comment: `def censor("this hack is wack", "hack"):` ... Nope not python :( You cannot declare literals inside function header. You can use it as `def censor(s = "this hack is wack", w = "hack"):`

Comment: This "code" is wrong on so many levels....

Comment: you will need to read a python tutorial. There's literally not a single line of code that is correct.

Comment: cant use `.replace` ?. Can we not be so critical of the OP ? hes clearly learning

Comment: This is what you have for _the tenth exercise_?

Comment: I notice that this is not the first time you've asked SO to complete a Codeacademy exercise for you. For the next five exercises, please read the instructional material instead of asking us to give you the answer, because I do not look forward to the eventual "I am trying to write a program for my job, but it doesn't work at all..." questions.

Comment: completely understood. ill get better with asking questions. i really wanna learn its not even about getting a job because i know this skill is going to be used for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with your code, since there is something wrong on almost every line:

```
def censor("this hack is wack", "hack"):
```

`def` means "define" and is how you, well, *define* a function. You seem to be confusing this with how you call one. In this, you need **variables** to call your parameters later. You have hard-coded string literals. This makes no sense and is not valid syntax.

```
def 'h,a,c,k'.split():
```

I don't even know what this means. `'h,a,c,k'.split()` is an almost no-op command, because `split()` by default splits on spaces, which the string `'h,a,c,k'` contains none of. Thus, that would return `['h,a,c,k']`. That is, it would return that if you issued the command properly. As it is you started defining a function and then began writing something else?

```
for letter in list:
```

This is fine, but `list` is a bad variable name, because you're overshadowing the Python built-in `list` function, which you might need later. (Or you might try to use it later, and it would behave incorrectly because you gave its name to something else.)

```
"*" 4
```

Sorry, I don't understand what you meant to do here either.

```
"".join(list)
```

Great, except you don't store it anywhere, and you do it once per loop instead of just once.

The function you're trying to write is something like this:

```
def censor(sentence, bad_word):
    return sentence.replace(bad_word, '*' * len(bad_word))
```

Then you **call** it like this:

```
censor('this hack is wack', 'hack')
"this **** is wack"
```

When you call the function like this, `'this hack is wack'` becomes `sentence` and `'hack'` becomes `bad_word` in the code inside your function. The function then uses the string's [`replace`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method to substitute a number of asterisks equal to the length of the "bad word" (`'*' * len(bad_word)`) for the "bad word" itself.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, but I think we both know that the OP will look through the code blocks and start copy-pasting them into Codeacademy until it accepts something.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should learn how to define functions.

Functions take in input as variables - not as literals.

So, your function starts off like this:

```
def censor(string):
```

You have to call your function with the given input. You want to input `"this hack is wack"`, so then your call is: `censor("this hack is wack")`.

Now, you need to figure out how to replace the word `"hack"` with `"****"`. The `str.replace` method does that just. Try this in a Python shell:

```
"this hack is wack".replace("hack", "****")
```

Putting this all together, you get:

```
def censor(string):
    return string.replace("hack", "****")

censor("this hack is wack")
```

If you want to have variable replacement, so that you can replace any word, your function should be:

```
def censor(string, to_censor):
    return string.replace(to_censor, "*" * len(to_censor))

censor("this hack is wack", "hack")
```

You should really look into a basic, introductory Python tutorial because your code was not correct in any way.

I suggest reading about [Python functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) first.

Comment: You're almost right but the function signature of `censor` is `censor(haystack, needle)`. That is, you're not supposed to hard-code "hack", but pass any "bad word" in as an argument and it will "censor" it for you by replacing it with asterisks.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I just added that in. Thanks, though :)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, but I think we both know that the OP will look through the code blocks and start copy-pasting them into Codeacademy until it accepts something.